# Replacing session_unregister with unset()

Tags: php, session

I'm moving a legacy system which I didn't create from one server (php 5.2) to a newer one (php 5.3) and a lot of the system uses session_unregister. I appreciate this is now deprecated in 5.3 so should I go ahead and replace all cases with unset($_SESSION['myVar']) or will this cause something to break?

Even better, is there an alternative that achieves the same function that I require, if unset() isn't the correct one

Comment: +1 for eliminating deprecated functions. `unset($_SESSION['key'])` should be fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can unset specific session vars using `unset($_SESSION['yourvar']);`, but mind this part from the manual:

> Do NOT unset the whole $_SESSION with unset($_SESSION) as this will
>   disable the registering of session variables through the $_SESSION
>   superglobal.

(from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php )

Comment: Alright thanks, is unset() the best way to do it then? (Just want to make sure I'm not replacing bad code with more bad code)

Comment: Yes it is: the note on the manual even suggests it, just above the yellow warning part.

Answer (score 0):

- session_unregister()

This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unregister.php

But if you need to "Free all session variables". Use

- session_unset();

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php